# Add custom exe app to windows image

Tags: windows, application, dism, executable

Is there possibility to add custom .exe application to Windows 10 image which will run in autostart when i install image on some computer? Either with DISM or ICD?

//EDIT:

App is without installer - its just few files + executable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, copy the files on the computer, then create a batch file here with the command to start your executable: `%WINDIR%\Setup\Scripts\SetupComplete.cmd` Windows will start the batch file after Windows setup.

[Learn more in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-custom-script-to-windows-setup)